# I can't type in EditText in Android fragment because the keyboard disappears

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-edittext

The problem is when I click on the `EditText` box in the fragment, the keyboard appears and then hides immediately, so I can't type in it.

This is layout for EditText:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/b2"
   android:visibility="visible"
   tools:context=".HomeFragment">

   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchUsersBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btns_style2"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:hint="ادخل اسم الشخص"
        android:padding="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I think the problem must be somewhere else. Not in the layout.

Comment: What event listeners do you have on the `<EditText>`.